# Error: Could not read config file

Tags: magento2, admin, configuration, product-images

Adding the actual product images to a live site, when upload a product image it says 'Could not read config file'

Any Suggestions? 
[image]

Comment: Please add more info or screenshot?

Comment: Added a screenshot - just an example product

Comment: This issue may be related to the config file, especially `etc/view.xml` file in the template.

Answer (score 3):

### The error

This is an exception that can be thrown in two methods of `lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Config/FileResolver.php` :

First in the `get` method:

```
$designPath = $this->resolver->resolve(
    RulePool::TYPE_FILE,
    'etc/view.xml',
    $this->area,
    $this->currentTheme
);
if (file_exists($designPath)) {
    try {
        $designDom = new \DOMDocument;
        $designDom->load($designPath);
        $iterator[$designPath] = $designDom->saveXML();
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
            new \Magento\Framework\Phrase('Could not read config file')
        );
    }
}
```

Second in the `getParents` method:

```
$designPath = $this->resolver->resolve(
    RulePool::TYPE_FILE,
    'etc/view.xml',
    $this->area,
    $this->currentTheme
);

if (file_exists($designPath)) {
    try {
        $iterator = $this->getParentConfigs($this->currentTheme, []);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
            new \Magento\Framework\Phrase('Could not read config file')
        );
    }
}
```

### The problem

To me, it sounds like a permission problem. In both cases, the system tries to load a `DOMDocument` by reading a specific path.

### Debugging

Here's my suggestion to easily find out which file is causing a problem.

I suggest you edit (temporarily, just the time of debugging) the two methods I mentionned above:

The `get` method, you can replace:

```
    throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
        new \Magento\Framework\Phrase('Could not read config file')
    );
```

With:

```
    throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
        new \Magento\Framework\Phrase('Could not read config file: %1', $designPath)
    );
```

For the `getParents` method, it's trickier as the load is made inside the `getParentConfigs` method.

Thus I suggest you do the following and replace:

```
    throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
        new \Magento\Framework\Phrase('Could not read config file')
    );
```

With:

```
    $parentDesignPath = $this->resolver->resolve(
            RulePool::TYPE_FILE,
            'etc/view.xml',
            $this->area,
            $this->currentTheme->getParentTheme()
        );
    throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
        new \Magento\Framework\Phrase('Could not read config file: %1', $parentDesignPath)
    );
```

Thanks to those modifications, you should be able to see the path causing issues directly in your error message.

Don't forget to rollback those changes once you found the problem.

Comment: great trick ! questions : is there a reason why error like these don't have paths/hints implemented in the error msg ? is it just for aesthetics reasons ? if the reason was roles related, is it worth it implementing this only for developer mode or is it overkill ?